# Cisco 1841 with Siemens Speedstream 6520 Modem

Tags: cisco

We have got Cisco 1841 with 2 Fastethernet ports. I have Siemens Speedstream 6520 Modem from my ISP. We are using ADSL (PPPOE connection). Do I need to do anything with the modem. I heard that I have to connect the modem into the bridge mode and then start configuring the Cisco router. Does anyone want to share experience with ADSL Modems and Cisco 1841 router configuration?

Thank you in advance for any replies..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general yes your ADSL modem will have to be set to bridge mode to work with a router. The reson for bridge mode is so the IP addess your get from your ISP is on the WAN interface of the router NOT the ADSL modem. Depending on how your ISP manages the hardware you may have to contact them to have bridge mode set.